# How do I remove these bathroom faucet handles?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink

I'm trying to replace the cartridge in a dripping sink, and I'm having trouble at the second step.

I have spent 20 minutes struggling with these handles, and I can't figure it out.

There is no screw that I can find.

I have put all my weight into lifting them off vertically.

I have pried and pried at the bottom cone-part to twist it off.

Nothing seems to work.

[image: Photo]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar fixture and found the part attached to the top of the sink unscrewed when turned counterclockwise. You might need to apply a bit of pressure to turn it if it has never been removed before.   Try a vise grip pliers with several layers of folded leather to protect the chrome finish.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it from the bottom, and at that point all may become clear.